# SQL Server 2016 - Dynamic date last four weeks (Saturday till friday)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, dynamic

I am using SQL Server 2016
I need two column populated with Dates.

Column one:
Lets say today is Wednesday 11/04/2020. i want dates from previous Friday (i.e. 10/30/2020 in this case) till four weeks back Saturday (i.e. 10/3/2020)

Column two:
In the next column , i want that week's Friday date repeating for the whole week, so that column should have four distinct dates.

it should look like this.

```
calDate     WeekendDate
10/3/2020   10/9/2020
10/4/2020   10/9/2020
10/5/2020   10/9/2020
10/6/2020   10/9/2020
10/7/2020   10/9/2020
10/8/2020   10/9/2020
10/9/2020   10/9/2020
10/10/2020  10/16/2020
10/11/2020  10/16/2020
10/12/2020  10/16/2020
10/13/2020  10/16/2020
10/14/2020  10/16/2020
10/15/2020  10/16/2020
10/16/2020  10/16/2020
10/17/2020  10/23/2020
10/18/2020  10/23/2020
10/19/2020  10/23/2020
10/20/2020  10/23/2020
10/21/2020  10/23/2020
10/22/2020  10/23/2020
10/23/2020  10/23/2020
10/24/2020  10/30/2020
10/25/2020  10/30/2020
10/26/2020  10/30/2020
10/27/2020  10/30/2020
10/28/2020  10/30/2020
10/29/2020  10/30/2020
10/30/2020  10/30/2020
```

**Update**

This below code gives me first column, i need to get the logic to populate the second column. Need help in getting fridays date for that relevant dates.

NOTE: Week in this case is from Saturday to friday

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DATE1') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #DATE1 
END;

DECLARE @tmpDates1 TABLE (calDate DATETIME)
DECLARE @beginDate DATETIME
SET @beginDate = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE())-5, 5)
WHILE @beginDate < DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE())-1, 5)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tmpDates1 ([calDate]) VALUES (@beginDate)
    SET @beginDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@beginDate)
END


SELECT * iNTO #date1 FROM @tmpDates1

select * from #date1
```

Comment: i have the first column logic, not sure how to get the friday dates for the relevant dates

Answer (score 1):

For this you will need one Date as comparison. Following an example:

```
DECLARE @CompFriday DATE = '2020-01-03'

DECLARE @t TABLE(
  MyDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('2020-11-04')
,('2020-11-05')
,('2020-11-06')
,('2020-11-07')
,('2020-11-08')
,('2020-11-09')
,('2020-11-10')
,('2020-11-11')

SELECT *
      ,DATEADD(d, -1 * DATEDIFF(d, @CompFriday, MyDate)%7, MyDate)
  FROM @t
```

Comment: Thanks Tyron this is working good. Is this going to work for every year when year changes since the @CompFriday is set up for this years first Friday ?

Comment: @Drake as long as the friday is in the past, this should work. We usually use some friday in 2000 or something since we don't work with data before this year.

Comment: @Drake did you already have the opportunity to check this solution with another year? If the the solution solved the problem, it would be great if you could accept my answer.